# Cannot take database backup in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

When I take database back up it's showing "Backup failed".

[image]

Comment: please paste the error as text

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d779d68b-1619-47ca-917a-d89f683dd428/restore-failed-with-data-error-cyclic-redundancy-check?forum=sqldatabaseengine